# How to make a button clickable only when a selected spinner value is selected in Android?

Tags: java, android, button, spinner

I want the button to be clickable only when a specific spinner value is selected. How can I do that? I tried this but it did not work. spLocation is my spinner name.

```
if (spLocation.getSelectedItem().equals("Bus Stop")) {
    btnRoute = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRoute);
    btnRoute.setClickable(true);
```

Comment: Maybe you add a listener to the Spinner and set the Button clickable in this part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
btnRoute.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if (spLocation.getSelectedItem().equals("Bus Stop")) {
            // Do your action
        } else {
            // Do your action
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
 String S = spLocation.getSelectedItem().toString();

    if(S!=null){

    btnRoute.setClickable(true);

    }else{

    btnRoute.setClickable(false);

   }
```